# Goroutine + channel execution order

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

I'm new to golang and want to understand deeply how `channel` works.
In the past I've made a basic multithreaded program with `.net` so I kinda now what `goroutine` is

I assume that `goroutine` is some kind of thread (actually a green thread) that will run concurrently with other `goroutine` so there's no guarantee for the execution order

but what I don't understand when you combine `goroutine` and `channel`

I know that you can use `channel` to guarantee the execution order of `goroutine` because it can block `goroutine`

Lets say I have a code like this

```
func greet(c chan string) {

    fmt.Println("Before print 1st item")
    fmt.Println("Hello", <-c)
    fmt.Println("After print 1st item")

    fmt.Println("Before print 2nd item")
    fmt.Println("Hello", <-c)
    fmt.Println("After print 2nd  item")

}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Main start")
    c := make(chan string)

     go greet(c)

    fmt.Println("Before insert 1st item")
    c <- "Alpha" // main goroutine blocked here and will be switched to another goroutine. Blocked because the channel is full or maybe I'm wrong here?
    fmt.Println("After insert 1st item")

    fmt.Println("Before insert 2nd item")
    c <- "Zebra" // why is it not blocked here ?
    fmt.Println("After insert 2nd item")

    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println("Main end")
}

//Output
Main start
Before insert 1st item
Before print 1st item
Hello Alpha
After print 1st item
Before print 2nd item
After insert 1st item
Before insert 2nd item
After insert 2nd item // why is it printed here ???
Hello Zebra
After print 2nd  item
Main end
```

Why is it printed like that ???

```
// My expectation
Main start
Before insert 1st item
Before print 1st item
Hello Alpha
After print 1st item
Before print 2nd item
After insert 1st item
Before insert 2nd item
Hello Zebra
After print 2nd  item
After insert 2nd item 
Main end
```

KeyPoint from what I understand

1. The `main` `gouroutine` blocked on this line `c <- "Alpha"` so it switched to `greet` goroutine
2. The `greet` `goroutine` will continue to execute until it blocked on the second `fmt.Println("Hello", <-c)`
3. Now `greet` `goroutine` is blocked and the `main` `goroutine` is not blocked because the string `Alpha` in `channel` already read and it will continue to execute

My question is why `main` `goroutine` is not blocked on this line `c <- "Zebra"` ?

I expected it to be blocked again just like in step 2 and will switch to `greet` `goroutine`

Based on this [doc](https://go.dev/tour/concurrency/2)

> By default, sends and receives block until the other side is ready. This allows goroutines to synchronize without explicit locks or condition variables.

Comment: there is two send op, there is two receive op, the code wont block.

Comment: Your understanding is wrong: While it is true that goroutines will yield if they are blocked, there is no guarantee they continue to run until they are blocked. All non-blocked goroutines run concurrently.

Comment: you can not deduce the execution behavior reading the terminal output, those routines are racing to write against a thread safe resource, there is no guarantee as to which will win.

Comment: Your key points are basically wrong. Nothing is "blocking" here. You have two goroutines and both are "running" all the time. All they do is to synchronize: Both goroutines execute the `<- c` in `fmt.Println("Hello", <-c)` and `c <- "Alpha"` "at the same time". The same holds for the next sync point. At any time not synchronised both goroutines are "running". Note that the print statements tell you nothing of the order between execution in the goroutines as these print statements are unsynchronised.

Comment: ah i see, thanks for helping me to understand

Answer (score 1):

Let's say channels are like a table. When somebody waits to receive from it, it is like you want to take something from the table. If there is anything, you take it and go, if there is nothing, you must wait for someone to put it over there. Same happens when you want to send at the channel. If there is nothing over the table, you just put the thing you have and leave, if there is something on it, you must wait for someone to take it to put your thing. (remember you can have a channel with space for more that one thing).

At the moment you get liberated, you keep doing whatever you want, no need to wait or syncronize. So you can't know what will happen before, because depending on the processing cycles you have been assigned you will get there before or after the other routines.

If you launch that a few times, you will see that different output appears.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).